# How to upload a PhoneGap project from VS2013 to Adobe Build?

Tags: c#, html, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I'm having some troubles when trying to upload my phoneGab project to the PhoneGap Build page. To begin with, I would like to let you know the tools I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2013
- PhoneGab 3.3.0
- Cordova (I guess it's 3.3.0)

And these are the steps I did, once I installed all the above:

1. After creating a phoneGap project in VS 2013, I copy the files inside the www folder that is generated as part of the project.
2. I zipped them (it contains the HTML, JS and CSS files. As well as the images)
3. I go to the phoneGap build page and log in
4. Then, I click on the upload App button and select the zip file that was created before
5. Once the zip file is loaded, the build phoneGap process generates the correspondents  files to each mobile platfform. Until here everything is OK

The problem is when I use my phone (lumia 920) to read the QR code to install the App. After the phone reads the QR code and try to install the App, I got an error messages saying that **the App of the company couldn't be install. Try to contact the support personal** .... something like that

This is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "helloworld.test"
    versionCode="10" 
    version   = "1.0.0">

<!-- For more information about using config.xml, see
    https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<!-- define which version of phonegap to use, not required -->
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />

<!-- this app will have no device api access -->
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

<!-- the default icon to be use, for BlackBerry must be less than 16kb -->
<icon src="img/logo.png" />

<!-- the default splash screen to use -->

<!-- iOS -->
<!--<gap:splash src="img/logo.png" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="img/logo.png" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="img/logo.png" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="img/logo.png" width="768" height="1024" /> -->

<!-- Android -->
<!-- <gap:splash src="img/logo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="img/logo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="img/logo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="img/logo.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" /> -->

<!-- BlackBerry -->
<!-- <gap:splash src="img/logo.png" gap:platform="blackberry" /> -->

<!-- Windows Phone -->
<gap:splash src="img/logo.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" />

<name>Hello LA PhoneGap</name>

<description>
    Simple example for phonegap usage. 
</description>

<author href="https://laphonegap.org" email="xxxxxxx@hotmail.com">
    Mike
</author>

</widget>
```

So, I'm not sure if a doing the correct steps to upload my phoneGap project to build it.

Do I missing something?

Any comment/help, would be very helpful.

Regards!

Comment: what does your config.xml look like? (what are the xmlns in the first line and does it contain reference for the plugins)

Comment: Hi QuickFix, I have updated the original question with the config.xml file I have so far

Comment: Have you registered your phone for development? (if not, check this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Hi again. Yes, I've done that. It was the least year. Indeed, I alredy have a Windows Phone App in the Store (Native App)

Comment: So I think we need the exact message. Is app installed and the message shows at startup or the error at installation?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The exact messages says: Can't install enterprise application. There is a problem with this enterprise application. Contact the enterprise technical support if you need help

Comment: sorry, no idea where this message comes from. I suggest you edit the question to put the exact message and make it more visible (begining of the question), maybe someone else will have more idea. And you didn't answer to other question in my previous comment.

Comment: I didn't notice the question before. Sorry about that. But the App isn't installed. The message comes up when trying to install the .xap package after reading the QR code from the build.phonegap.com page.

Comment: Have you tried use the url from the Install page in your phone browser? (maybe it's something to do with your qrcode app?)